# How to create a custom Hyperlink in excel in the Home tab to different tabs in the same workbook?

Tags: excel, hyperlink, excel-2010

I have been doing this task manually and I want to figure out an easier and quicker way of doing this task in MS excel 2010. My workbook has 100's of tabs. I need to create a Hyperlink to each tab with the tab name in the "Home" tab. I am following the following steps for now

•   Go to the tab

•   Right click Rename, copy name

•   Click on Name on A1 Cell, right click Hyperlink

•   Click on Place in the Document pick "Home"

•   Now go to Home Tab

•   Click on next available cell, Paste name, then right click select Hyperlink, Select the appropriate Tab and click ok.

How can I achieve the same results using some feature in MS excel 2010?

Thanks!

Comment: Searching the internet is more effective when you use the most accurate terms. The "tabs" in Excel are called **Sheets**, and the content you want to make is called an **index**. Searching Google for **excel index of sheets** yields multiple results containing VBA code and step by step instructions for your task.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily with a macro.  No hyperlinks necessary.  In whichever sheet you're in create a BeforeRightClick event and use code similar to this, you may need to adapt to fit your needs.

```
For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name = Target Then
        Cancel = True
        ws.Activate
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Suppose you have a sheet named "Data" and in cell "A1" of the worksheet with the macro in it you type "Data".  If you right click on that cell it'll take you to the Sheet named "Data". By doing this you can reference any sheet in your workbook and back to your main sheet as well.

Answer (score 0):

This VBA script worked exactly how I wanted it to. Just sharing in case someone else stumbles across the same scenario.

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Dim wSheet As Worksheet
Dim l As Long

l = 1

```
With Me
    .Columns(1).ClearContents
    .Cells(1, 1) = "INDEX"
    .Cells(1, 1).Name = "Index"
End With


For Each wSheet In Worksheets
    If wSheet.Name <> Me.Name Then
        l = l + 1
            With wSheet
                .Range("A1").Name = "Start_" & wSheet.Index
                .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Range("A1"), Address:="", _
                SubAddress:="Index", TextToDisplay:= .Range("A1").Text
            End With

            Me.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Me.Cells(l, 1), Address:="", _
            SubAddress:="Start_" & wSheet.Index, TextToDisplay:=wSheet.Name
    End If
Next wSheet
```

End Sub